# Optimizing for critical rendering path when using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Would it be possible to optimize for the critical rendering path (similar to what Google and Facebook are doing) if I am using Bootsrap 3?

Facebook just inlined the styles that are related to the header and sidebars.
Google inlined all the styles because they do not have much styles for the homepage.

The issue here is that let's say I want to inline styles related to my header, it would consist of over 10 classses used from bootstrap (`container-fluid`, `row`, `col-lg-10`, `col-lg-offset-2`, etc..).
And inlining bootstrap is a bad idea because it is over 100kbs

I want to load above the fold content, really quick.

Is there a smart way of doing it? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Applying CSS rules is a blistering very fast process -- it's very unlikely that the CSS itself is the problem. Usually network IO is the bottleneck meaning that conglomerated and miniffied css/js is usually enough to make things work as fast as possible.

Comment: Avoiding FOUC should be easily achieved by moving structural CSS to its own separate file. For example a file containing only sizing and positioning rules (display, position, width, height, margin, border, padding) only for rendering the header/footer/sidebar (main viewable).

Answer (score 1):

This technique is independent of your framework, Bootstrap in this case.
You have to come up with a way to figure out your critical CSS which you can extract and inline into your HTML file.
There are many ways to do so:

- Custom critical CSS file (created manually)
- Type annotations in your CSS file, which could be extracted on compile/build time: https://css-tricks.com/annotating-critical-css/
- Automated using [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)

This topic is way too big to answer in a short thread so feel free to read up on the topics listed above:
https://web.dev/extract-critical-css/

Tools:

- [Critical](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical)
- [criticalCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/criticalCSS)
- [Penthouse](https://github.com/pocketjoso/penthouse)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't start doing in-line styles just yet, there are many optimisations that can be done before you'd ever need to go down that route. Plus there is a massive trade off, performance of the duplicated styles in the HTTP request (could be a double edged sword) and a maintenance nightmare.

1. Load CSS in head.
2. Load JS at end of body.
3. Customize bootstrap to only include the minimum required styles.
   http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
4. Bundle & minimize your header related files in a separate bundle, think about segregating bootstrap components. Bundling gives caching and minification.
5. Single paged application, be smart about your initial load page and use modules/web components to ajax in templates of html.
6. Use CDN's as there are maximum http connections per host.

More can be found at https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: Inlining critical CSS makes a *big* difference when it comes to avoiding FOUC and empty pages. Your page will appear to load much faster as it doesn't need to wait for an additional network response before beginning to construct the CSSOM.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer is that **you shouldn't have to add extra inline code for performance reasons**. Your best bet to minimize loading time would be (as suggested above) to use the bootstrap customiser to remove whatever classes you won't be needing and also minify and gzip (if possible) before sending. Most of the times you'll need a lot less than the 100kbs bootstrap css.

However, rendering the elements in the browser is more costly than applying classes to them. You can only minimize load times up to a point.

You haven't told us what kind of performance you expect; but if it was a life-or-death kind of situation to super extra fast load the header, yes you should use inline code.